# Intuitive understanding of the Halmos-Savage theorem

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, intuition, sufficient-statistics, measure-theory

The [Halmos-Savage theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177730032) says that for a dominated statistical model $(\Omega, \mathscr A, \mathscr P)$ a statistic $T: (\Omega, \mathscr A, \mathscr P)\to(\Omega', \mathscr A')$ is sufficient if (and only if) for all $\{P \in \mathscr{P} \} $ there is a $T$-measurable version of the Radon Nikodym derivative $\frac{dP}{dP*}$ where $dP*$ is a privileged measure such that $P*=\sum_{i=1}^\infty P_i c_i $ for $c_i >0, \sum _{i=1}^\infty c_i =1$ and $P_i \in \mathscr P$.

I have tried to get an intuitive grasp why the theorem is true but I did not succeed, so my question is whether there is an intuitive way to understand the theorem.

Comment: I believe I have the correct link here. Please check & remove it if I made a mistake.

Comment: Maybe help the reader with terminology, e.g., define "dominated statistical models", "$T$-measurability" and "privileged measures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## A Technical Lemma

I'm not sure how intuitive this is, but the main technical result underlying your statement of the Halmos-Savage Theorem is the following:

> **Lemma.**
>   Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(S, \mathcal{A})$.
>   Suppose that $\aleph$ is a collection of measures on $(S, \mathcal{A})$ such that for every $\nu \in \aleph$, $\nu \ll \mu$.
>   Then there exists a sequence of nonnegative numbers $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and a sequence of elements of $\aleph$, $\{\nu_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i = 1$ and $\nu \ll \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i \nu_i$ for every $\nu \in \aleph$.

This is taken verbatim from Theorem A.78 in [Schervish's *Theory of Statistics* (1995)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-4250-5).
Therein he attributes it to Lehmann's *Testing Statistical Hypotheses* (1986) ([link to the third edition](https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-27605-X)), where the result is attributed to [Halmos and Savage](https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177730032) themselves (see Lemma 7).
Another good reference is [Shao's *Mathematical Statistics* (second edition, 2003)](https://doi.org/10.1007/b97553), where the relevant results are Lemma 2.1 and Theorem 2.2.

The lemma above states that if you start with a family of measures dominated by a $\sigma$-finite measure, then in fact you can replace the dominating measure by a countable convex combination of measures from within the family.
Schervish writes before stating Theorem A.78,

> "In statistical applications, we will often have a class of measures, each of which
>   is absolutely continuous with respect to a single $\sigma$-finite measure. It would be
>   nice if the single dominating measure were in the original class or could be constructed
>   from the class. The following theorem addresses this problem."

## A Concrete Example

Suppose we take a measurement of a quantity $X$ which we believe to be distributed uniformly on the interval $[0, \theta]$ for some unknown $\theta > 0$.
In this statistical problem, we are implicitly considering the set $\mathcal{P}$ of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of the uniform distributions on all intervals of the form $[0, \theta]$.
That is, if $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure and, for $\theta > 0$, $P_\theta$ denotes the $\operatorname{Uniform}([0, \theta])$ distribution (i.e.,
$$
P_\theta(A)
= \frac{1}{\theta} \lambda(A \cap [0, \theta])
= \int_A \frac{1}{\theta} \mathbf{1}_{[0, \theta]}(x) \, dx
$$
for every Borel $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$), then we simply have
$$
\mathcal{P} = \{P_\theta : \theta > 0\}.
$$
This is the set of candidate distributions for our measurement $X$.

The family $\mathcal{P}$ is clearly dominated by Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ (which is $\sigma$-finite), so the lemma above (with $\aleph = \mathcal{P}$) guarantees the existence of a sequence $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of nonnegative numbers summing to $1$ and a sequence $\{Q_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of uniform distributions in $\mathcal{P}$ such that
$$
P_\theta \ll \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i Q_i
$$
for each $\theta > 0$.
In this example, we can construct such sequences explicitly!

First, let $(\theta_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be an enumeration of the positive rational numbers ([this can be done explicitly](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7643/225635)), and let $Q_i = P_{\theta_i}$ for each $i$.
Next, let $c_i = 2^{-i}$, so that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i = 1$.
I claim that this combination of $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and $\{Q_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ works.

To see this, fix $\theta > 0$ and let $A$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i Q_i(A) = 0$.
We need to show that $P_\theta(A) = 0$.
Since $\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i Q_i(A) = 0$ and each summand is non-negative, it follows that $c_i Q_i(A) = 0$ for each $i$.
Moreover, since each $c_i$ is positive, it follows that $Q_i(A) = 0$ for each $i$.
That is, for all $i$ we have
$$
Q_i(A)
= P_{\theta_i}(A)
= \frac{1}{\theta_i} \lambda(A \cap [0, \theta_i])
= 0.
$$
Since each $\theta_i$ is positive, it follows that $\lambda(A \cap [0, \theta_i]) = 0$ for each $i$.

Now choose a subsequence $\{\theta_{i_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of $\{\theta_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ which converges to $\theta$ from above (this can be done since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$).
Then $A \cap [0, \theta_{\theta_{i_k}}] \downarrow A \cap [0, \theta]$ as $k \to \infty$, so by continuity of measure we conclude that
$$
\lambda(A \cap [0, \theta])
= \lim_{k \to \infty} \lambda(A \cap [0, \theta_{i_k}])
= 0,
$$
and so $P_\theta(A) = 0$.
This proves the claim.

Thus, in this example we were able to explicitly construct a countable convex combination of probability measures from our dominated family which still dominates the entire family.
The Lemma above *guarantees* that this can be done for any dominated family (at least as long as the dominating measure is $\sigma$-finite).

## The Halmos-Savage Theorem

So now on to the Halmos-Savage Theorem (for which I will use slightly different notation than in the question due to personal preference).
Given the Halmos-Savage Theorem, the Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem is just one application of the Doob-Dynkin lemma and the chain rule for Radon-Nikodym derivatives away!

> **Halmos-Savage Theorem.**
>   Let $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{P})$ be a dominated statistical model (meaning that $\mathcal{P}$ is a set of probability measures on $\mathcal{B}$ and there is a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}$ such that $P \ll \mu$ for all $P \in \mathcal{P}$).
>   Let $T : (\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B}) \to (\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{C})$ be a measurable function, where $(T, \mathcal{C})$ is a standard Borel space.
>   Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $T$ is sufficient for $\mathcal{P}$ (meaning that there is a probability kernel $r : \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{T} \to [0, 1]$ such that $r(B, T)$ is a version of $P(B \mid T)$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and $P \in \mathcal{P}$).
> 2. There exists a sequence $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of nonnegative numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i = 1$ and a sequence $\{P_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of probability measures in $\mathcal{P}$ such that $P \ll P^*$ for all $P \in \mathcal{P}$, where $P^* = \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i P_i$, and for each $P \in \mathcal{P}$ there exists a $T$-measurable version of $dP/dP^*$.

*Proof.*
By the lemma above, we may immediately replace $\mu$ by $P^* = \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i P_i$ for some sequence $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of nonnegative numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i = 1$ and a sequence $\{P_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of probability measures in $\mathcal{P}$.

(1. implies 2.)
Suppose $T$ is sufficient.
Then we must show that there are $T$-measurable versions of $dP/dP^*$ for all $P \in \mathcal{P}$.
Let $r$ be the probability kernel in the statement of the theorem.
For each $A \in \sigma(T)$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
P^*(A \cap B)
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i P_i(A \cap B) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i \int_A P_i(B \mid T) \, dP_i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i \int_A r(B, T) \, dP_i \\
&= \int_A r(B, T) \, dP^*.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus $r(B, T)$ is a version of $P^*(B \mid T)$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

For each $P \in \mathcal{P}$, let $f_P$ denote a version of the Radon-Nikodym derivative $dP/dP^*$ on the measurable space $(\mathcal{X}, \sigma(T))$ (so in particular $f_P$ is $T$-measurable).
Then for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and $P \in \mathcal{P}$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(B)
&= \int_{\mathcal{X}} P(B \mid T) \, dP \\
&= \int_{\mathcal{X}} r(B, T) \, dP \\
&= \int_{\mathcal{X}} r(B, T) f_P \, dP^* \\
&= \int_{\mathcal{X}} P^*(B \mid T) f_P \, dP^* \\
&= \int_{\mathcal{X}} E_{P^*}[\mathbf{1}_B f_P \mid T] \, dP^* \\
&= \int_B f_P \, dP^*.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus in fact $f_P$ is a $T$-measurable version of $dP/dP^*$ on $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$.
This proves that the first condition of the theorem implies the second.

(2. implies 1.)
Suppose one can choose a $T$-measurable version $f_P$ of $dP/dP^*$ for each $P \in \mathcal{P}$.
For each $B \in \mathcal{B}$, let $r(B, t)$ denote a particular version of $P^*(B \mid T = t)$ (e.g., $r(B, t)$ is a function such that $r(B, T)$ is a version of $P^*(B \mid T)$).
Since $(T, \mathcal{C})$ is a standard Borel space, we may choose $r$ in a way that makes it a probability kernel (see, e.g., Theorem B.32 in Schervish's *Theory of Statistics* (1995)).
We will show that $r(B, T)$ is a version of $P(B \mid T)$ for any $P \in \mathcal{P}$ and any $B \in \mathcal{B}$.
Thus, let $A \in \sigma(T)$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$ be given.
Then for all $P \in \mathcal{P}$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A \cap B)
&= \int_A \mathbf{1}_B f_P \, dP^* \\
&= \int_A E_{P^*}[\mathbf{1}_B f_P \mid T] \, dP^* \\
&= \int_A P^*(B \mid T) f_P \, dP^* \\
&= \int_A r(B, T) f_P \, dP^* \\
&= \int_A r(B, T) \, dP.
\end{aligned}
$$
This shows that $r(B, T)$ is a version of $P(B \mid T)$ for any $P \in \mathcal{P}$ and any $B \in \mathcal{B}$, and the proof is done.

> **Summary.**
>   The important technical result underlying the Halmos-Savage theorem as presented here is the fact that a dominated family of probability measures is actually dominated by a countable convex combination of probability measures from that family.
>   Given that result, the rest of the Halmos-Savage theorem is mostly just manipulations with basic properties of Radon-Nikodym derivatives and conditional expectations.